# Python - Unexpected behaviour with lambdas when iterating

Tags: python

I'm looking to create and store a specific function for each key of a dictionary. However, I've noticed that whenever I try to iterate through my set of keys (By creating an iterable then manually iterating, using a comprehension, and by the "for" loop), all of the functions turn out the same:

```
>>> numbers = list(range(10))
>>> functions = {}
>>> for number in numbers:
        functions[number] = lambda: number
# I'd expected the call functions[2]() should return 2

>>> two_function = functions[2]
>>> two()
9
```

Could someone explain why this happens and how to fix this?

Comment: See ["Why do lambdas defined in a loop with different values all return the same result?"](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-do-lambdas-defined-in-a-loop-with-different-values-all-return-the-same-result).

Comment: Consider the result of `print(number)`

Comment: Note, the "principled" way to do this is to use a factory function: `def make_func(number): return lambda: number` and then use `functions[number] = make_func(number)` in your loop.or you can take advantage of the default argument trick, although that may be considered a bit hackey, but it is a common enough idiom

Answer (score 1):

This is a fun little twist in Python.  The `lambda` there is returning the `number` object.  By the time the loop ends, the `number` object has the value 9.  What you need is a trick called "capturing":

```
    functions[number] = lambda n=number: n
```

That "captures" the value at the point the lambda is defined.

Comment: I wouldn't say this is really a twist in Python, it is merely the consequence of lexical scoping, which is pretty standard among modern languages. It is no more exotic than `x = 0; def foo(): print(x); x= 1; foo()`